# Why does TIGERweb API give different census block info than the FCC block API

Tags: arcgis-server, api, census

Here is the block API request and result:

```
https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/block/find?latitude=42.6692833&longitude=-73.7315867&format=xml

<Response status="OK" executionTime="0">
<Block FIPS="360010001001020" bbox="-73.733132,42.667491,-73.727983,42.672319"/>
<County FIPS="36001" name="Albany"/>
<State FIPS="36" code="NY" name="New York"/>
</Response>
```

Here are the requests to TIGERweb (one for 2010 and another for 2020):

```
https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_Census2020/MapServer/10/query?where=&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-73.7315867%2C42.6692833&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=block%2Ctract%2Cstate%2Ccounty&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4236&havingClause=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=html

# records: 1

BLOCK: 1003
TRACT: 000100
STATE: 36
COUNTY: 001

https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/tigerWMS_Census2010/MapServer/18/query?where=&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-73.7315867%2C42.6692833&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4236&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=block%2Ctract%2Cstate%2Ccounty&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4236&havingClause=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=html

# records: 1

BLOCK: 1041
TRACT: 000100
STATE: 36
COUNTY: 001
```

Note that I get three different blocks? I expect the 2010 TIGERweb result to match the result from the block API, but the blocks don't match.

Why?

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about its quality is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I noticed a typo on the 2020 TigerWeb inSR 4326 instead of 4236. Maybe that will fix it?

Comment: Changing it got me this: GEOID: 360010001001032

Comment: Thanks Jason for catching this. Unfortunately the result is yet another bock #. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake on my part. When I reran the queries, being careful to get the inputs consistent, the results of block API did match that of the 2010 TIGERweb query. So false alarm....